# How do I change strength of emission at Principled BSDF

Tags: emission

I want to keep the settings except emission and only change the strength of it like the emission node. Any ways?

Comment: This emission strength could be added to the Principled BSDF in the near future, since a [patch](https://developer.blender.org/D4971) for this is being implemented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Blender 2.92 + :**

In the newer versions the principled BSDF shader actually has a field for emission strength, right below the emission color field. You can use it much like the simpler Emission Shader.

You can still input color values superior to 1, but there is no need anymore with the new strength field.

[image]

**Older Versions :**

You can manually input values higher than 1 in the red,green,blue fields of the emission color of the principled shader. Keep in mind that this is a workaround and will not mimic exactly how a classic emission shader works when you tweak its strength.

[image]

For ease of use you can use such a setup : Add an rgb node in order to input the exact color you want the emission to be, a value node for the strength of the emission, and link both of them to the color inputs of a mix rgb node set to multiply with a factor of 1, then set the output of the mix rgb to the emission input of the bsdf.

[image]

Comment: Aaah, finally! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a mix shader. Be aware that your Prinipled BSDF emission should be set to black (none) so as to not influence the emission shader

[image]

Comment: I'm worried about that 'factor'. Doesn't it make all other things(Base color, Subsurface and so on) dim and weaken their influence if it's set lower than 1?

Comment: @김준형 Indeed, this method is not physically accurate. A better way would be to use the "Add Shader" node instead of the "Mix Shader" node.

Comment: @Bauxite  Thanks!